# How do I declare a return type of a tuple of two numbers?

Tags: typescript

When I declare a function as

```
const coordinates = (id: number): ([number, number]) => {
```

the error I get is `[ts] Duplicate identifier 'number'.`

If I omit type signature for return value, then it infers it as `number[]`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
const coordinates = (id: number): [number, number] => [id, id];
```

No need for the parenthesis around the return tuple type

Comment: this answer is outdated, the newer answer from Alexandre Hitchcox using `as const` allows to omit the arrow function return type (which can be hard to get right when that includes lengthy generic types from a 3rd party library).

Answer (score 25):

```
const coordinates = (id: number) => [id, id] as const;
// const coordinates: (id: number) => [number, number]
```

From TypeScript 3.4 onwards you can use const assertations.